# How to create article-quality 3-D plots?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

Lately I've been working on how to make my MATLAB figures article-quality, since normal output plots don't look that nice. The function [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/file_infos/23629-exportfig) from the File Exchange has done a lot of pretty things for me, but now I've come to a new challenge: making a high-quality 3-D plot.

I figured the best place to start looking is here, so my question is: how to make a good-looking 3-D plot using only MATLAB? And don't get me wrong, I know *how* to make a 3D plot, I just want my figures to be looking article-quality!

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is a bit unclear. Are you having trouble generating high quality 3-D plots, or simply experiencing loss of quality when exporting them to image files?

Comment: I'm sorry for any unclarity. I mainly asked to question to obtain some general ideas of how others are managing to generate article-quality 3D plots using only Matlab. I hope that clarifies?

Comment: This is exactly the point that confuses me: what do you mean by "_article-quality_"? In my mind _article-quality_ is obtained by producing high-quality plots and then exporting them to high-quality images. If you have one without the other, the outcome will be low-grade. Which one of the two are you asking about, perhaps it is both?

Comment: Ok, yes I have a hard time expressing my question I see. My question is what kind of 3D plot functions would be suitable for generating _article-quality_ plots. Specifically I have a time-evolution of a distribution which I would like to plot in 3D, in this case I've tried `mesh` and `surf` but both give rather ugly output plots which I can't see myself using in an article. I mainly posted the question to hopefully get some new ideas or insights.

Comment: Actually `surf` and `mesh` can produce really nice plots. It's all about playing with the edges and with the illumination (_e.g_ see the plots [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/creating-mesh-and-surface-plots.html?s_tid=doc_12b)...). If you post a simplified example of what you're doing and specify what you don't like in that plot, it'll really help.

Comment: Hmm...then I might've given up on these functions too fast. I'll give that another try. Thanks for your help Eitan! Can't get into it now, but when I get to it I'll post some results in an answer here. To be continued...

Comment: Consider posting them as an edit to your question. Good luck!

Comment: P.S: here's a related article by [Loren Shure](http://stackoverflow.com/users/113700/loren): [_Making Pretty Graphs_](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/12/11/making-pretty-graphs/). It's worth a read!

Comment: Oh yeah that was the first article I bumped into on my survey into this. Very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are satisfied with the figure's quality on screen, you can just save the figure in `.eps` fully-vectorized format. Then open it - on OSX I use the standard `preview` software - and save it as a light `.jpg` for the initial submission, and as `.tiff`, `png` or `pdf` depending on the journal requirements. `preview` can export an `.eps` at 600/1200 pixels per inch, compressed or not, and cropping is easily done with a mouse. *A minor point: vectorized exported figures do not render unfamiliar fonts.*

Here is an [example from matlab](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/streamtube.html), exported as `.eps` and saved as `.png` 400 ppi.

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but so far I had the impression that matlab's export to eps ignores many of the 3D features (e.g. light, shades etc).

Comment: @H.Muster limits must exist but I have often been satisfied by the rendering.

Comment: Again I might be wrong, but I think that matlab exports the shiny surfaces as raster graphics even when exporting to eps, i.e., the final eps file will not be a "clean" eps.

Comment: @H.Muster that's true - if a 3D figure is doubled in size, then the eps format export is much bigger - vector plots should not -

Answer (score 1):

try enabling handle graphics 2 if you are on one of the later versions of Matlab. Use
`-hgVersion 2` startup switch in your Matlab command-line.

Comment: A good overview of the HG2 graphics can be found at [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/).